# pivot wider from long dataframe

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I have:

```
df = tibble(row = 1:10,
            n = as.character(c(1,1,1,1,1, rep(2,5))),
           n2 = n,
           metric = rep(LETTERS[1:5],2),
           value = as.character(c(1:10)))
```

And I want

[image]

I tried
`df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = metric, values_from = value) %>% select(-row)`, but this returns

[image]

Comment: `df %>% pivot_wider(-row, names_from = metric, values_from = value)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `row` first, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 select(-row) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = metric, values_from = value)

 n     n2    A     B     C     D     E    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     1     1     2     3     4     5    
2 2     2     6     7     8     9     10
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also specify `id_cols`:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(n, n2), names_from = metric, values_from = value)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  n     n2    A     B     C     D     E    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     1     1     2     3     4     5    
2 2     2     6     7     8     9     10
```

Answer (score 1):

the `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), n + n2 ~ metric, value.var = "value")
#    n n2 A B C D  E
# 1: 1  1 1 2 3 4  5
# 2: 2  2 6 7 8 9 10
```